# DynamicJasper: How to fix java.lang.NoSuchMethodError error

Tags: jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I have a example for dynamic jasper report.

I am using NetBeans IDE.

I include library files as follows :

```
Dynamic-jasper-3.2.1.jar
Dynamic-jasper-3.2.1-test.jar
jasperreport-4.5.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.2.jar 
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar 
commons-digester-1.7.jar 
commons-logging-1.1.jar 
junit-3.8.2.jar
```

```java
import java.util.Date;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperDesignViewer;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.DynamicReport;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.builders.FastReportBuilder;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.test.BaseDjReportTest;

public class FastReportTest extends BaseDjReportTest {
    public DynamicReport buildReport() throws Exception {

        FastReportBuilder drb = new FastReportBuilder();
        drb.addColumn("State", "state", String.class.getName(), 30)
                .addColumn("Branch", "branch", String.class.getName(), 30)
                .addColumn("Product Line", "productLine", String.class.getName(), 50)
                .addColumn("Item", "item", String.class.getName(), 50)
                .addColumn("Item Code", "id", Long.class.getName(), 30, true)
                .addColumn("Quantity", "quantity", Long.class.getName(), 60, true)
                .addColumn("Amount", "amount", Float.class.getName(), 70, true)
                .addGroups(2)
                .setTitle("November \"2006\" sales report")
                .setSubtitle("This report was generated at " + new Date())
                .setPrintBackgroundOnOddRows(true)
                .setUseFullPageWidth(true);

        DynamicReport dr = drb.build();
        return dr;
    }

    public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception {
        FastReportTest test = new FastReportTest();
        // test.
        test.testReport();
        test.exportToJRXML();
        JasperViewer.viewReport(test.jp);    //finally display the report report
        JasperDesignViewer.viewReportDesign(test.jr);
    }
}
```

I have Got error like this :

```
Feb 17, 2012 10:30:58 AM ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper generateJasperReport
INFO: generating JasperReport
Feb 17, 2012 10:30:58 AM ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper generateJasperReport
INFO: generating JasperReport
Feb 17, 2012 10:30:58 AM ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DJJRDesignHelper getNewDesign
INFO: obtaining DynamicJasperDesign instance
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.DynamicJasperDesign.setPrintOrder(B)V
    at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DJJRDesignHelper.getNewDesign(DJJRDesignHelper.java:69)
    at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperDesign(DynamicJasperHelper.java:207)
    at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperReport(DynamicJasperHelper.java:535)
    at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperReport(DynamicJasperHelper.java:518)
    at ar.com.fdvs.dj.test.BaseDjReportTest.testReport(BaseDjReportTest.java:83)
    at FastReportTest.main(FastReportTest.java:34)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: Version 3.2.1 supports up to jasper reports 4.0

Comment: it depends on pom.xml, i dont think DJ 3.2.1 supports jasper-report4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you are using the `DynamicJasper 3.2.1` you should use the externals libraries from the `DJ`'s pom.xml.

The snippet of the pom.xml file:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
        <artifactId>xwork</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
       <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
        <artifactId>webwork</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge</groupId>
        <artifactId>barbecue</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As you can see this version (3.2.1) of `DJ API` is using `jasperreports 3.7.1` and etc.

Comment: its just a xml file or special type of file...??
how to add this file...??

Comment: Did you hear about the [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)? You should use the correct version of libraries (in module dependencies).

Comment: i dont know nything about Maven...?? Is it related to DJ..?? i am using latest libraries, check the starting of my question... If it is nt latest thn tell me...

Comment: You should not use the latest version of libraries. You should use the same versions as in posted pom.xml file. For example, you should use `jasperreport-3.7.1.jar`. You can read about the `Apache Maven` - there are a lot of books and articles.

Comment: got it... i ll try for it.. if any need thn tell u.... thnk u very much...

Comment: but how to open pom.xml file....!!! can i edit this file...??

Comment: In your case (the `Maven` tool is unknown for you) you can use the pom.xml file as "a simple list" of libraries that you should include to classpath. You do not need to edit this file, it is just for information (in your case). In future you can create the maven based application.

Comment: still i got the error : part 1 :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/DocumentException
 at ar.com.fdvs.dj.test.ReportExporter.exportReport(ReportExporter.java:63)
 at ar.com.fdvs.dj.test.BaseDjReportTest.exportReport(BaseDjReportTest.java:108)
 at ar.com.fdvs.dj.test.BaseDjReportTest.testReport(BaseDjReportTest.java:97)
 at FastReportTest.main(FastReportTest.java:34)

Comment: part 2 :Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lowagie.text.DocumentException
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
 ... 4 more
Java Result: 1

Comment: You should add the `itext 2.1.7` library to the classpath